# Combine multiple lists of classes into 1 list

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a class, that contains a list of classes, which in them selves, contains a list of classes, as below:

```
public class grouping
{

    public List<Member> members { get; set; }
    public string group_id { get; set; }
}

public class Member
{
    public string member_id { get; set; }
    public List<vStat> vstats { get; set; }
}

public class vStat
{
    public string t1 { get; set; }
    public string t2 { get; set; }
    public string t3 { get; set; }
    public string v_id { get; set; }
}
```

Each List vstats contains a number of vStats, where v_id only occurs once per list, but each members vstats list will repeat these v_id's. t1,2 and 3 are all integers, but unfortunately are stored in strings. I could cast them earlier if needs be, but was hoping to do all this in one go.

What I want to do is combine each Members vstats list into a single list for all members, with a single value for each v_id and the sum of the values for t1,t2,t3:

I can do this with a number of loops inside loops, but it seems there should be a more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

```
members.SelectMany(m => m.vstats)
       .GroupBy(v => v.v._id)
       .Select(g => new vStat {
           t1 = g.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.t1)).ToString(),
           t2 = g.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.t2)).ToString(),
           t3 = g.Sum(x => Int32.Parse(x.t3)).ToString(),         
           v_id = g.Key
       });
```

This query returns single list of aggregated `vStat` objects for all members.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `List<grouping>` then you can first flatten its `members` and then its `vStats` using `SelectMany` and then you can project the result like:

```
List<grouping> groupList = new List<grouping>();
var result = groupList.SelectMany(grp=> grp.members)
                      .SelectMany(mem=> mem.vstats)
                      .GroupBy(v => v.v_id)
                      .Select(vgrp=> new vStat 
                      {
                          v_id = vgrp.Key, 
                          t1 = vgrp.Sum(r=> int.Parse(r.t1)).ToString(),
                          t2 = vgrp.Sum(r=> int.Parse(r.t2)).ToString(),
                          t3 = vgrp.Sum(r=> int.Parse(r.t3)).ToString()
                      });
```

Not really sure how much faster it is as compare to your loop code since it internally uses loops.